# Can you change text "XXX Wants to use your location"

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, geolocation, location

When a website requests for permission to use the users location through html5, is there a way to change the message that pops down?

Ultimately, I would like to have a pop up dialog, that would tell them why we're asking for their location, and if they press yes, it automatically 'accepts' or creates permission to use their location, rather than them having to press 'okay' twice, effectively.

So, Can you change the browser text?

And, can you control the button in the browser dialog/popdown?

Comment: Yes we can by using custom jQuery dialog..

Comment: I would say no. This would pose a serious security risk if you could change the text to say "click okay to view this page" and then the browser gave away their location information. For this reason, I would suggest that you alert the user as to why you are about to request location information, and after they "accept" your alert, actually request the location (and they will - as you say - have to press 'okay' twice).

Comment: @OllieBennett, I get the security risk, however getting the html5 location coordinates, aren't accurate at all. They're just a close approximate.

Comment: The only "proof" I can find (which hints that the button text will always be "Accept") is here: "Your location is sent to the site only if you click Allow in the prompt." https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065
Chrome specific, of course.

Comment: I know what it say's by default, I'm asking if it's possible to change...